# Devise Rails Password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have a new application that the root user create another users, when i create the user with the model.

```
 @user = User.new(:email => params[:email], :password => params[:password], :password_confirmation => params[:password_confirmation])
 @user.save!
```

The users saves "correctly" on the table on "encrypted_password" the value and the others fields too, but when i try to login i have an error
"Invalid Email or Password" so when i read the record the password is.

```
encrypted_password: $2a$11$wFnpiA.l9HezNXfnAGkttuu2IGIXByETytLrEkdDsa8sBFrc8Bdmq
```

But i used another password the root password that actually works.
But on the table is :

```
 encrypted_password: $2a$11$VKOAUk5pjILU1QHYmkpJSem9KKm70QJPS7Oj.nPM/pTuyu1tqZaQO
```

So, my model of the devise is not saving the correct encryption of the password.

My TestController:

```
 class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @Users = User.all
  end

 def create
     begin
        @user = User.new(:email => params[:email], :password => params[:password_first], :password_confirmation => params[:password_confirmation])
        @user.save!
        flash[:notice] = "Usuario creado correctamente"
        redirect_to action: 'index'  
     rescue Exception => e          
          flash[:alert] = "Error al crear al Usuario: " + e.message
          redirect_to action: 'index'  
     end
 end

end
```

What am i doing wrong?

Regards

Comment: Never do `rescue Exception => e` its a really bad practice that will swallow basic errors such `NoMethodError` and syntax errors and make debugging very difficult. Use `if @user.save` and render the new view if false so that the user can correct any validation errors. Rescue should not be used for normal control flow.

Comment: Hi, i only try to figure out this.
My user has this pass: 123
and the password on the table is :
$2a$11$VKOAUk5pjILU1QHYmkpJSem9KKm70QJPS7Oj.nPM/pTuyu1tqZaQO
But when i create a new user on the model the password change to:
 $2a$11$drZIcAsXTHxyvtbvL3Wg5e0EPG4JJpsAlmxe78ohEjDSA3/nCzHoa
Thats my question why the model doesn't use the encryption of Devise.

Comment: Well `rescue Exception => e` does nothing except sweep the errors under the mat.

Comment: As a note, if you're new to Ruby you may want to steer towards using the modern `(x: y, a: b)` style hash notation. `:x => y` is a relic from the Ruby 1.8 days and while still prevalent in a lot of code bases, is a lot more noisy and ugly looking than the alternative.

Comment: Bcrypted passwords, which is what Devise uses by default, are intended to hash differently every time. You could create a thousand hashes with the password "test" and they'd all be different. The verification routine takes care of all this for you.

Comment: Better yet would be to use form_for with a User instance and the whitelist the parameters with `params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)`. If you are ever literally copying a hash key by key  you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Ohhh i get it i though that was like md5/sha, thanks for the reply.

Comment: Besides this controller is it a vanilla devise setup or have you done any monkeying with user model that might explain it?

Comment: And is the parameter really `password_first` and not just `password`? It might help if you include the form and the input parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BCrypt goes out of its way to scramble the password as much as possible to make it extremely difficult to reverse that hashing operation. For any given input string to `BCrypt::Password.create` there are around 680 trillion-trillion-trillion possible output strings (2<sup>128</sup>), so it's unlikely you'll ever get the same one twice:

```
hashes = 10.times.map { BCrypt::Password.create('test') }
# => [
#   "$2a$10$vMrgjJHqvwnEKIs0fZ76pO3gbWL/0C3ExqK9HOpi/mHYu2.4GAO2K",
#   "$2a$10$KxBOarDzRPHp7QF1GGqNnuplRs1B5rNVfp21IHx1/HzQ0YIcIkLRW",
#   "$2a$10$emCdZAA.GU8GwQZkeJLfAuUTY2aEnhFmZ.GQAhDpJ.JGSh/m6s/k2",
#   "$2a$10$6R6xmGyK7Tb1MKsQb00vpOJKwpi56aj98JLoBJhBN4vWSQb7zagQm",
#   "$2a$10$r4qmb.C.vm88pL2nJK5TdOaWIboYaO6a1xHIRH.QDER6qYR6Ajvo.",
#   "$2a$10$mlVWz4IHTgYHSf3tAgEgpenpDHtGWYev4EUENLs7hnLlm6ikPhUxy",
#   "$2a$10$ixXdZZuc9rIVAozO8tyq5.wlsVOWBc6QWetNh3PvjPj2pGlqh.XOy",
#   "$2a$10$zLzuevtOl.g4RbaHpdeTZ.k4qjE/1m4nh6gN4mhcIKQPSa5sBcG5u",
#   "$2a$10$F/F71.DYEuzxS4W0w5m/a.IRpaVJxeh9sKUJ7DyQb5xU3SvFu1Ib.",
#   "$2a$10$ILXg8R52ZtHHbQbT0FxSFOj8YNqpNLmrH.6FhM3RGMwIuBeP1YXHa" ]
```

This is alright though since the verification routine can handle checking password:

```
hashes.map { |h| BCrypt::Password.new(h) == 'test' }
# => [true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true]
```

They all match. It's important to note that verifying ten passwords does take a small but noticeable amount of time. This is what make BCrypt particularly well suited to password storage: Guessing is expensive so throwing huge dictionaries of words at a hash to see which match is extremely difficult. This is not the case with weaker hashes like MD5 or SHA1 where a million operations per second is completely feasible. BCrypt is deliberately about a half million times slower.

Answer (score 0):

Start with a regular decent Rails crud setup and see if the issue does not solve itself.

```
# routes.rb
resources :users, only: [:create, :index]
```

---

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user!

  # GET /users
  def index
    @Users = User.all
  end

  # POST /users
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      flash[:success] = "Usuario creado correctamente"
      redirect_to action: :index
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def user_params
     params.require(:user)
           .permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
end
```

---

```
# app/views/users/_form.html.erb
<% form_for(@user || User.new) do |f| %>
  <% if f.object.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(f.object.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this article from being saved:</h2>
    <ul>
      <% f.object.errors.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.email_field :email %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <%= f.password_field :password %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
  </div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

---

```
# app/views/users/new.html.erb
<%= render partial: 'form' %>
```

You can embed the partial in your root view or the users index by:

```
<%= render partial: 'users/form' %>
```

Note that you should render and not redirect if the record is invalid. If you redirect the users input and any validation messages you want to show are gone.